# Adding id value into ecaxtly id column

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm using SQL Managment Studio to connect my database and I'm trying to add some rows into it in Windows App using Stored Procedures. 
Whenever I add a row the `id` value adds into a new `column1` as it shown at the screenshot. How can i fix it?

```
dataGridView1.Columns["id"].ReadOnly = true;
```

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [schedule]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_insertProduct]
    @date date,
    @less_n int,
    @teacher nchar,
    @room int,
    @gr int,
    @subject nchar
AS
    INSERT INTO dbo.main(date, less_n, teacher, room, gr, subject) VALUES
    (@date, @less_n, @teacher, @room, @gr, @subject)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM0OK.jpg)

Comment: Can you also share the stored procedure statements? Ideally, your `id` column should have `IDENTITY(1,1)` so there should be no need to mention it anywhere in the query. It will increment automatically.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny here it is